# Can we set two gravity for single textview

Tags: android

I have to set two gravity for single TextView is it possible

similar like this,

```
  This line is example|
      Center Text     |
             I m right|
```

I have to achive this in a Single TextView so please do not suggest me to declare two textview one with TextView1 CENTER gravity and another TextView2 with RIGHT gravity.

Is it Possible with Span or Html or any other property.

Comment: Downvote please explain

Comment: I guess you can use `<div align = "...">`. See the [supported HTML tags in TextViews](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) (Thanks to @CommonsWare for the list). But then... why not using a `WebView`? It would give you a more complete HTML support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved problem using Spannable

`spannablecontent.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(
                        Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE),
                        0, 15,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

For Single TextView we  can assign it as

Left = ALIGN_NORMAL

Center = ALIGN_CENTER

Right = ALIGN_OPPOSITE .

Answer (score -2):

If you want only a single textview for all, using HTML would give you the solution. I have posted it below.

activity_main

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/html_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String htmlText = "<body><p>This line is example|  " +"<br>"+ 
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Center Text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|" +"<br>"+
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am right|";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView htmlTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.html_text);
        htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));

    }


}
```

Now you can change the text color or anything you like with HTML

Comment: And how are you supposed to calculate how many spaces are needed to center or to right align a text on multiple screen resolutions? By the way, if using this horrible method, you don't even need HTML at all.